# Is there an HTML AMPScript Outputter / Render?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I am looking to for something to compile amp script and generate the final html based on pre-defined or static variables. Is there an application or plugin for this?

Comment: You can do this using Test and Preview tab in Content Builder, when editing an email. Why is that not sufficient? There are no specific tools to "convert" Ampscript to HTML outside of content builder.

Comment: Use a cloudpage define static or dynamic variables in ampscript variables. You can just set them in ampscript or define them in a dataextension and change them "dynamic". If you need subscriber context, fake it unless you need to use ampscript functions that are limited to email only.

Comment: @LukasLunow because i don't care as much about how it looks but rather what html it generated. I can have an issue with the amp script function, no error generated and it'll still display correctly but that doesn't change that the html didn't generate correctly.